# How are pages reallocated in a a data file after shrinkfile sql server

Tags: sql-server, shrink

I understand that shrinking the data files is a bad idea in SQL Server due to index fragmentation.
I want to ensure that I completely understand before arguing my point.
I know that when `dbcc shrinkfile` (unless with `truncateonly`) is run, the pages from the back are moved to free spaces in an earlier position.

Does this function get the very last page in the data file and place it in the first available space?

In other words, if we have this situation:

```
[ Page 1 ] [ Page 2 ] [ empty1 ] [ empty2 ] [ Page 3 ] [ Page 4 ] [ empty3 ] [ empty4 ] [ Page 5 ]
```

...after executing a `dbcc shrinkfile` would `[ Page 5 ]` be moved to `[ empty1 ]` because that is the first available slot? and so on...

In the end it eventually would look like this:

```
[ Page 1 ] [ Page 2 ] [ Page 5 ] [ Page 4 ] [ Page 3 ]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shrink algorithm works exactly as you described it. A good description can be found in Paul Randal's blog: https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/why-you-should-not-shrink-your-data-files/

> Why does this happen? A data file shrink operation works on a single
>   file at a time, and uses the GAM bitmaps (see Inside The Storage
>   Engine: GAM, SGAM, PFS and other allocation maps) to find the highest
>   page allocated in the file. It then moves it as far towards the front
>   of the file as it can, and so on, and so on.

In your example, Page5 ends up in Empty1.